# Adding UIActivityIndicatorView on Synchronous Web Service data and Populating UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am fetching the data from a web service by synchronous method. I make the request to the web service then view freezes. I try to add the UIActivityIndicatorView before loading the data from the web service and stopped it after getting the data but activity indicator is not displayed.
I tried to put the web service data fetch operations on the different thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchRequest) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

but at this time TableView crashes as it does not get the data for drawing the cells. 
in fetchRequest function I am doing

```
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                          URLWithString:URLString]];
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *tableData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&jsonParsingError];


        responseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[tableData objectForKey:@"data"]];

        for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.count; i++)
        {
            NSArray * tempArray = responseArray[i];
            responseArray[i] = [tempArray mutableCopy];
        }
```

This `responseArray` is used to fill the information in the cell
Please tell me how to do this. Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your very approach. `Synchronous` methods run on the main thread. And because the UI updates on the main thread, your app *hangs*.

So, the solution would be using an `asynchronous` method to download the data on a separate thread, so that your UI won't *hang*.

So, use the `NSURLConnection`'s `sendAsynchronousRequest`. Here's some sample code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_HERE"];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    //this is called once the download or whatever completes. So you can choose to populate the TableView or stopping the IndicatorView from a method call to an asynchronous method to do so.
}];
```

Comment: how to fill the uitableview data with this because it crashes when the tableview cells are created.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use Grand Central Dispatch to fetch the data like this so you dispatch it in a background queue and do not block the main thread which is also used for UI updates:

```
 dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(myqueue, ^(void) {

    [self fetchRequest];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update UI on main queue
 [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    });
```

Regarding the Activity indicator you can use in the start of the parsing:

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES
```

And then when your table is filled with data:

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: but problem is that it crashes because the tableview cells are loaded on main thread simultaneously.

Comment: @Atul edited my answer. Try this. If this does not do the trick, probably the crash is related to how you fill the table cells.

Comment: How to fill the table cells?

Comment: have you implemented the UITableViewDelegate methods? like cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40417/discussion-between-atul-and-nikos-m)